# Extracting several "next siblings" from HTML with BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a collection of HTML files which share the following structure:

```
<h1>ITEM NAME</h1>
<span class="standardLabel">Place of publication: </span>PLACENAME
<br /><span class="standardLabel">Publication dates: </span>DATE
<br /><span class="standardLabel">Notes: </span>NOTES
<br /><span class="standardLabel">Frequency: </span>FREQUENCY
```

What I want to extract is all the information indicated in BOLD, but I was only able to write a script that captures the "item name" and "place name":

```
# import packages

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from os.path import dirname, join
directory=("C:\\Users\\mobarget\\Google Drive\\ACADEMIA\\10_Data analysis_PhD\\NLI Newspaper DB")

# search information in each file

for infile in os.listdir(directory):
    filename=join(directory, infile)
    indata=open(filename,"r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") 
    contents = indata.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'html')
    newspaper=soup.find('h1')
    if newspaper:
        print("Title of file no.", str(infile), ": ", newspaper)
        place=soup.find("span",{"class":"standardLabel"}).next_sibling
        print(place)
    else:
        continue
```

The output is:

```html
Title of file no. 1 :  <h1>About Town</h1>
Dungannon, Co. Tyrone

Title of file no. 10 :  <h1>Amárach: Guth na Gaeltachta</h1>
Dublin, Co. Dublin

Title of file no. 100 :  <h1>Belfast Election</h1>
Belfast, Co. Antrim
```

[etc.]

Any ideas how I could extract the missing data without making the code too redundant?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selector `span:contains("<YOUR STRING>")` to find specific `<span>` tag and then do `.next_sibling`.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''<h1>ITEM NAME</h1>
<span class="standardLabel">Place of publication: </span>PLACENAME
<br /><span class="standardLabel">Publication dates: </span>DATE
<br /><span class="standardLabel">Notes: </span>NOTES
<br /><span class="standardLabel">Frequency: </span>FREQUENCY'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

title = soup.h1.text
place = soup.select_one('span:contains("Place of publication:")').next_sibling.strip()
dates = soup.select_one('span:contains("Publication dates:")').next_sibling.strip()
notes = soup.select_one('span:contains("Notes:")').next_sibling.strip()
freq = soup.select_one('span:contains("Frequency:")').next_sibling.strip()

print(title)
print(place)
print(dates)
print(notes)
print(freq)
```

Prints:

```
ITEM NAME
PLACENAME
DATE
NOTES
FREQUENCY
```

Comment: Thanks, the CSS selector works really well. However, `soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')` does not seem to work in Python3. I got the notification that "txt" was not defined and had to stick with "contents" instead.

Comment: @OnceUponATime Yes, I have `txt` only defined in my example. If you have `contents` in your program, use it!

Answer (score 0):

Using the code from Andrej Kesely's answer, I have also added exception handling for missing attributes:

```
# import packages

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from os.path import dirname, join
directory=("C:\\Users\\mobarget\\Google Drive\\ACADEMIA\\10_Data analysis_PhD\\NLI Newspaper DB")

# read downloaded HTML files

for infile in os.listdir(directory):
    filename=join(directory, infile)
    indata=open(filename,"r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") 
    contents = indata.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
    newspaper=soup.find('h1')
    if newspaper:
        try:
            # read data from tags
        
            title = soup.h1.text
            place = soup.select_one('span:contains("Place of publication:")').next_sibling.strip()
            dates = soup.select_one('span:contains("Publication dates:")').next_sibling.strip()
            notes = soup.select_one('span:contains("Notes:")').next_sibling.strip()
            freq = soup.select_one('span:contains("Frequency:")').next_sibling.strip()

            # print results

            print("Title of file no.", str(infile), ": ", title)
            print(place)
            print(dates)
            print(notes)
            print(freq)

            # exception handling if attributes are missing

        except AttributeError:
            print("no data")
            
    else:
        continue
```